# MAMP Pro cannot load or run from Kohana application's index.php. Displays "Index of /"

Tags: php, macos, indexing, kohana, mamp

I have an existing Kohana 3.3 web application that I moved from a windows/linux environment to a Mac OSX 10.8.4. The application runs perfectly on windows and linux, of course, but I'm having trouble trying to get it started on my Mac.

I'm using MAMP PRO and I have set its configuration to the best of my knowledge. Anyhow, the issue is that when I tried to access the app as https://subdomain.domain.local, the page displays "Index of /" and a list of the directory content of where my index.php file is. However, if I go straight to a controller as so: https://subdomain.domain.local/login, the page works perfectly and I'm able to use the app.

Why is MAMP PRO not able to initialize or run from index.php?

Comment: I was able to fix this myself. I was removed the "Directory Index" option that I had assigned within MAMP PRO under "Others" tab for my particular host. Restarted Apache and MySQL, so then going to my domain i.e. `https://subdomain.domain.local` works just fine.

Comment: Please, post this fix as an answer and mark it as the answer so it is clear this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this was to remove in MAMP PRO the path I had set in the Directory Index text field of the Others tab for my particular host. Here's my setup for running an SSL web app that's placed on another location other than MAMP PRO's htdocs folder:

Under hosts->General, I added my server name (i.e. `subdomain.domain.local`), checked local name resolution, and SSL, port 443 for Server Setting text box, and Disk Location points to the folder path where your Kohana's index.php file is (also make sure that you have permission's to your web app folder)

Advanced tab: I have the options Indexes, FollowSymLinks checked; and also AllowOverride: All; Order: Allow,Deny; Allow: from all

SSL tab: set the paths to your self-signed certificates for both certificate file and certificate key (if you don't have one, create one using the Create button).

Also, make sure that your ports are correctly set under Server->General. I have Apache 80, SSL 443, MySQL 3306.

That's it. I had other issues with MAMP PRO's MySQL, but that's a different issue.